# Generating Entity List property for "Reusable Content" list

Tags: 2010, linq, spmetal

I am attempting to generate an entity class for "Reusable Content" list.  After running the CKSDEV tool, i see that DataContext object has the following

```
/// <summary>
/// Items in this list contain HTML or text content which can be inserted into web pages. If an item has automatic update selected, the content will be inserted into web pages as a read-only reference, and the content will update if the item is changed. If the item does not have automatic update selected, the content will be inserted as a copy in the web page, and the content will not update if the item is changed.
/// </summary>
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ListAttribute(Name="Reusable Content")]
public Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.EntityList<Item> ReusableContent {
    get {
        return this.GetList<Item>("Reusable Content");
    }
}
```

The strange thing is that returns a list of Item class and not custom child class like i was expecting. Note, SPMetal also created created ReusableHtml and ReusableText.  However, how do I retrieve "Reusable HTML" and Reusable Text" columns then?